# Show span tags based on checkbox checked or unchecked by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have below view page in ASP.NET MVC3, 
Based on checkbox selection i need to show associated span tag.

**Ex:**

In 1st  tag, 1st td has span tag, 2nd td has checkbox, 3rd td has some message.
if the checkbox is checked hide span tag which is in 1st td.
if the checkbox is unchecked show span tag.
I need to show the span tag specific to particular checkbox is checked or unchecked.

**Sample Example:**
if the 1st  checkbox is checked, hide span tag which is in same 1st
if the 2nd  checkbox is unchecked, show span tag which is in same 2nd

Now i am wondering how would i go about, showing span tag which is based on checkbox selection, anyone help me out.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg1"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus1", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg2"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus2", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg3"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus3", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg4"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus4", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg5"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus5", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg6"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus6", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="errorMsg7"  class='errorMessage' style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
        <\td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus7", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
        </td>
        <td>Message7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery.ready(function domReady($) {
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function () {
            $('#spBlueCheckbox').slideToggle(this.checked);
        });
    });
    $('#BtnAccept').click(function () {
        if ($('input:checkbox').length == $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {
            alert('All are not checked')
            $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('.errorMessage').show();
            $('#errorMsg').show();
            $('#spMsgError').show();
            $('#spMsgError').html("Please confirm all the items above, and place a check mark in every confirmation box.");
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
            return false;
        }
        else if ($('input:checkbox').length != $('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
            alert('few boxes not checked');

     //show only span tag whose checkboxes are not checked

            $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('input:checkbox:checked').removeClass("outLineRed");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('all are checked')
            $('input:checkbox:checked').removeClass("outLineRed");
            $('.errorMessage').hide();
            $('#spMsgError').hide();
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: corrected all the IDs to be unique.

Comment: Have you tried: `$(this).closest("span").slideToggle(this.checked);`?

Comment: @Govinda : Don't know who did that. but question is not clear ie. not readable to understand it easily. Grammar ki dhajjiya udadi yaar.

Comment: @MelanciaUK tried.. not working..

Comment: Why do you have two document ready handlers nested? `jQuery.ready(function domReady($) { jQuery(function ($) {`

Comment: An example: http://jsfiddle.net/x7a5C/1/ Source: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar modified the question

Comment: If you used `label` instead of `span` it would make your life easier, but that's just a tip.

Comment: @MelanciaUK i saw your jsfiddle, it seems working fine there, the same thing i need to put in the else if block, bcoz i need to validate this on button click

Comment: @MelanciaUK based on your tip, i have completed this and it is working now. Thanks, you can post your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Just did it. Glad you got yourself sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use the `jQuery Tree Traversal` methods to find the related `span`.

You can adapt the code below to fit your purpose, but the idea will remain the same:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').find('span').slideToggle(this.checked); 
    });
});
```

Note that you're nesting two `document ready` event handlers, so get it sorted out too.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7a5C/1/)

[jQuery Tree Traversal documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: Unless it's there for another reason, yes. Or you can just remove the other one and leave everything inside `domReady`.

Answer (score 1):

Base on MelanciaUK's answer, i am posting this answer with little modification to the question point and it is working as expected. It will help other folks.

```
jQuery().ready(function domReady($) {    
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function () {            
            $('#spBlueCheckbox').slideToggle(this.checked);
        });
    });   
    $('#BtnAccept').click(function () {
        if ($('input:checkbox').length == $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {            
            $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");           
            $('.errorMessage').show();           
            $('#spMsgError').show();
            $('#spMsgError').html("Please confirm all the items above, and place a check mark in every confirmation box.");
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
            return false;
        }
        else if ($('input:checkbox').length != $('input:checkbox:checked').length) { 
            $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function () {
                $(this).parents('tr').find('span.errorMessage').show(!this.checked);               
            });
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                $(this).parents('tr').find('span.errorMessage').hide(this.checked);              
            });
            $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('input:checkbox:checked').removeClass("outLineRed");            
            return false;
        }
        else {            
            $('input:checkbox:checked').removeClass("outLineRed");
            $('.errorMessage').hide();           
            $('#spMsgError').hide();
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
        }       
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of slideToggle you can use toggle. In IE10 the slideToggle sometimes works abnormally.

```
$('#spBlueCheckbox').slideToggle(this.checked);
```

Insteady of above one use below

```
$('#spBlueCheckbox').toggle(this.checked);
```